# How to test EDGE or GPRS or any other slow/bad network

Tags: ios, reachability, gprs, cellular-network, core-telephony

In my iOS app, I support to work online as well as offline. For this I have used [Apple's Reachability code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html). Now I want to show user is offline if the cellular mobile network is EDGE or GPRS or bad/slow network. I have used the below code( Found [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999601/how-can-i-programmatically-detect-edge-network-or-bad-network-in-iphone/19999966#19999966) ).

**Code:**

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *telephonyInfo = [CTTelephonyNetworkInfo new];
NSLog(@"Current Radio Access Technology: %@", telephonyInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology);
[NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserverForName:CTRadioAccessTechnologyDidChangeNotification 
                                                object:nil 
                                                 queue:nil 
                                            usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) 
{
    NSLog(@"New Radio Access Technology: %@", telephonyInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology);
}];
```

I did testing on device with `3G cellular mobile network` and got `CTRadioAccessTechnologyWCDMA` successful. To test `EDGE` or `GPRS` or any other `slow/bad network` I used [Network Link Conditioner](http://www.myuiviews.com/2014/01/15/ios-network-link-conditioner.html) from device's developer settings but still getting `CTRadioAccessTechnologyWCDMA` value.

**EDIT:**

After doing so many researches, I have found another [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8254327/1635315) which measures signal strength. I have tested this on iOS7 device it works but not in iOS8.4 device. Also I think this is private API so may apple will reject this.

Here is my code:

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>
#import <dlfcn.h>

int CTGetSignalStrength();

@implementation ViewController
-(int) getSignalStrength
{
    void *libHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony", RTLD_LAZY);
    int (*CTGetSignalStrength)();
    CTGetSignalStrength = dlsym(libHandle, "CTGetSignalStrength");
    if( CTGetSignalStrength == NULL) NSLog(@"Could not find CTGetSignalStrength");
    int result = CTGetSignalStrength();
    dlclose(libHandle);
    return result;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}
-(void)updateLabel{
    _lblSpeed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"signal strength: %d\n", CTGetSignalStrength()];
    NSLog(@"signal strength: %d\n", CTGetSignalStrength());
}
@end
```

So any idea how we can test for EDGE or GPRS or any other slow/bad network? Is there any another solution/idea to proceed?

Comment: The Network Link Conditioner simulates slow speeds as if you were on edge/3g/etc, but it doesn't simulate the cellular radio you're connected to. Have you tried to test this on a device that's actually connected to EDGE network or something else?